# Understanding watermark behaviour when using Kafka connector and Flink SQL

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a problem with understanding how watermarks are assigned when using Kafka connector and Flink SQL. I have inserted messages into kafka topic in given order:

```
1. A,2023-07-08 09:00:00,2023-07-08,1.0 
2. A,2023-07-08 09:00:01,2023-07-08,2.0
3. A,2023-07-08 09:02:01,2023-07-08,2.0
4. A,2023-07-08 09:03:00,2023-07-08,4.0
5. A,2023-07-08 09:03:01,2023-07-08,5.0
6. A,2023-07-08 09:04:01,2023-07-08,6.0
7. A,2023-07-08 09:03:10,2023-07-08,5.35
```

Now I have a source:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE source_kafka_test (
  `symbol` VARCHAR(2147483647),
  `msg_ts` TIMESTAMP(3),
  `trade_date` VARCHAR(2147483647),
  `trade` DOUBLE,
  WATERMARK FOR `msg_ts` AS `msg_ts` - INTERVAL '1' MINUTES
)
WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'format' = 'csv',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '',
  'topic' = '', 
  'properties.group.id' = '',
  'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset'
);
```

Now I order events by `msg_ts` (watermark) and print a simple select:

```
create temporary view raw_data_sorted AS (
    select
        symbol,
        msg_ts,
        trade_date,
        trade
    FROM source_kafka_test
    order by msg_ts ASC
);

select * from raw_data_sorted;
```

My results:

```
symbol  msg_ts              trade_date  trade
            
A       2023-07-08T09:00    2023-07-08  1.0
A       2023-07-08T09:00:01 2023-07-08  2.0
A       2023-07-08T09:02:01 2023-07-08  2.0
```

I run this query on preexisting data in kafka topic (all entries exist in kafka before running the query)

It seems the value for watermark is taken from the last entry (2023-07-08 09:03:10) and because of this only first 3 entries are printed (other will be printed after watermark advances).

When I first run Flink SQL job and then insert the same messages into kafka all of them are printed (current watermark is 2023-07-08 09:04:01 - aligned with my understanding)

The question is why this current watermark value is different depending on when the query is executed? (after data is inserted or before data is inserted).

It results in non-deterministic results when running this query for the second time, for ex. some late events are considered non-late and taken into account when performing calculations or some windows may never be closed (or may be closed late) if the last message in kafka was the last trade (in this day)

Answer (score 0):

After ingesting the 7 events in your example, the watermark will be the largest timestamp (2023-07-08 09:04:01) minus 1 minute, minus 1 millisecond -- or 2023-07-08 09:03:00.999. Any events later than this watermark won't be emitted by the sorting query until a larger watermark comes along.

When Flink jobs end cleanly, Flink send through one final watermark with a huge timestamp. This then triggers the emission of any remaining (buffered) rows.

I'm not sure this explains everything you reported, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thank you David, this is aligned with my understanding. Your description is correct when events are added to kafka in "live"/streaming mode, when Flink job is running before any event is added to kafka. However your description is not correct when Flink processes already existing data (more like batch however in both cases I run Flink in streaming mode). In this "batch" case it looks like the last read value is taken as a watermark, ignoring previous `msg_ts`. I don't understand this second case.

Comment: According to your example, since the watermark is 2023-07-08 09:03:00.999
event no 4 should be printed (4. A,2023-07-08 09:03:00,2023-07-08,4.0) but is not.

Comment: Another factor is that watermarks are not generated after every event, or at every conceivable moment. By default the runtime generates a new watermark every 200msec, if there's justification for doing so (i.e., new events).

Comment: It's not clear when or how your job stopped running, which will also have an effect.

Comment: My job didn't start working or I stopped it manually but it shouldn't matter.
Maybe I'll put it this way: I have two jobs: A and B - the same logic, the same deployment mode etc. I start job A, insert some events into kafka, then I start job B. Jobs print some results but these results are different. Why?
I set watermark interval to 1msec, the same results.